rendering text in Unity causes huge garbage collector work and slower productivity (low fps)
i'm writing a visual novel and i've noticed an issue. My script is BIG (has a lot of text i mean) and the more process of game i get the more time i need to wait to render the text. it just appears slower and slower.
here is an image. it shows that i reserve about 2GB. 2GB for visual novel!! can't beleive in it. here is the text rendering fuction:
private IEnumerator Build_Fade()
    {
        int minRange = pre_text_len;
        int maxRange = minRange + 1;
        byte alphaThreshold = 15;
        TMP_TextInfo textInfo = tmpro.textInfo;
        Color32[] vertexColors = textInfo.meshInfo[textInfo.characterInfo[0].materialReferenceIndex].colors32;
        float[] alphas = new float[textInfo.characterCount];
        while (true)
        {
            float fadeSpeed;
            if (hurryup)
            {
                fadeSpeed = character_per_cycle * 5 * speed * 4f;
            }
            else fadeSpeed = character_per_cycle * speed * 4f;

            for (int i = minRange; i < maxRange; i++ )
            {

                TMP_CharacterInfo characterInfo = textInfo.characterInfo[i];
                if (!characterInfo.isVisible) continue;
                int vertexIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].vertexIndex;
                if(i >= alphas.Length)
                {
                    alphas = new float[textInfo.characterCount];
                }
                alphas[i] = Mathf.MoveTowards(alphas[i], 255, fadeSpeed);
                
                for (int v = 0; v < 4; v++)
                {
                    vertexColors[characterInfo.vertexIndex + v].a = (byte)alphas[i];
                }
                if (alphas[i] >= 255)
                {
                    minRange++;
                }
            }
            tmpro.UpdateVertexData(TMP_VertexDataUpdateFlags.Colors32);
            bool lastCharacterInvisible = !textInfo.characterInfo[maxRange - 1].isVisible;
            try
            {
                if (alphas[maxRange - 1] > alphaThreshold || lastCharacterInvisible)
                {
                    if (maxRange < textInfo.characterCount)
                    {
                        maxRange++;
                    }
                    else if (alphas[maxRange - 1] >= 255 || lastCharacterInvisible)
                    {
                        DIALOGUE.ConversationManager.userPrompt = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Clear();
            }
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        

    }

the try-catch block is used in very special cases - sometimes when i tap really quickly(tap but don't skip the text like i can do in novels) this error occurs (index was out of range). but this doesn't happen every time and the issue happened when there was no try-catch block.
i don't know much about memory usage and the GC role in C# so I have clearly no idea what to do
I used profiler in Unity to track the memory usage so here is the result, check the image

This probably needs more info. What is TMP_TextInfo and TMP_CharacterInfo? How does this render the text? Why is it called BuildFade if it does rendering? Where is the text stored? And so on

Oh sorry I forgot that only I know my code   I will edit the answer soon @SamiKuhmonen

Check the detail view. 2GB is not a suprise if you have a lot of images in the memory.

@SamiKuhmonen sorry i was on my way. i searched the info it is the UNITY class for rendering text

@shingo okay maybe it's quite normal but look at the FPS. it goes 15 FPS more and more frequently. that's bad

Then you need to take a look at the CPU usage tab, this is different to the memory issue.

I forgot to close another tab, it caused double rendering. That was the reason
